# Change signs in a squared equation in Maple

Tags: maple

I want to change the signs of all symbols in a squared equation in Maple. For example, these equations yield identical answers:

1. ((-a + b - c + d)^2) / (a - b)
2. ((a - b + c - d)^2) / (a - b)

Now let's say I have coded the first function in Maple using:

test := (-apple + banana - cherry + date)^2/(apple - banana)

I can then easily swap these with:

numer(test)/denom(test), because the numer() changes the signs.

However, if I use different labels, such as swap "apple" with "quality", this doesn't work anymore.

test := (-**quality** + banana - cherry + date)^2/(apple - banana);
numer(test)/denom(test)

Could you explain why and how it can be achieved instead?

Comment: It's because when you use numer and denom, Maples expands everything "under the hood" and gives an answer that may not be what we expect.  The expansion will be  different when apple is part of the denominator and numerator then when it isn't.  There is a post here that alludes to the issue - https://mapleprimes.com/questions/230061-Why-Maple-Did-This-Automatic-Simplification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to handle your examples,

It acts on all squares of sums in the expression. It maps `-` across the sum subexpression.

```
sw:=e->subsindets(e,`+`^2,
                  u->subsop(1=map(`-`,op(1,u)),u)):

expr:=((-a+b-c+d)^2)/(a-b):

sw(expr);

   (a-b+c-d)^2/(a-b)

 test:=(-quality+banana-cherry+date)^2/(quality-banana):

sw(test);

   (quality-banana+cherry-date)^2/(quality-banana)
```

Here's a variant on that.

```
sw:=e->subsindets(e,`+`^2,
              u->map(`-`,op(1,u))^2):
```

You could also make it work on other even powers.

```
sw:=e->subsindets(e,`+`^even,
              u->map(`-`,op(1,u))^op(2,u)):

expr2:=(a-b)/(-a+b-c+d)^4:

sw(expr2);

   (a-b)/(a-b+c-d)^4
```